# Сделать надпись в 3D

Tags: html, css

```css
div {
  background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e9/2f/03/e92f03ace41d591e3c3f7454105dcffb.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Картинка внутри текста
</div>
```

Как сделать этот текст в 3D, что нужно использовать за свойство?

Comment: это как 3d пример есть

Comment: Ну с добавлением свойства text-shadow,получается своеобразный текст в 3D, но тут это свойство не работает, видимо из-за изображения внутри

Answer (score 0):

Диву добавляете свойство "text-shadow" (например: text-shadow: 2px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);). Более детально http://gering111.com/12-primerov-text-shadow/

```css
div {
      background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e9/2f/03/e92f03ace41d591e3c3f7454105dcffb.jpg);
      background-attachment: fixed;
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
      font-size: 100px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
      text-shadow: 2px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    }
```

```html
    <div>
      Картинка внутри текста
    </div>
```